# How do i convert a Brush datatype to Color in c#, WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am currently trying to convert a brush type to color using this code

Color a = (brush1 as SolidColorBrush).Color;

but i am getting a Nulpoint exception.Can anyone help?

Comment: The brush1 object is either null, or not SolidColorBrush. Just put a breakpoint on that line and check it.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. apparently it was due to the brush1 not getting any value assigned.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `as` operator returns `null` if the cast does not succeed. So your brush is not a `SolidColorBrush` or `null`.

Comment: i have tried doing this using this too: 
Brush ab = new SolidColorBrush();
ab = brush1;
Color a = (ab as SolidColorBrush).Color;
but i get the same error NUll point execption

Answer (score 0):

The null reference exception is most likely because the cast is failing. You can confirm whether this is the case by trying a direct cast:

`Color a = ((SolidColorBrush)brush1).Color;`

and seeing whether that throws a casting exception instead.

Comment: I am still getting the same error :(
It is saying i need to create a new object instance

Comment: How is 'brush1' being instantiated and used - does its 'Color' property get set at some point point - either at instantiation (using the constructor of the form `new SolidColorBrush(Color)`) or directly set at some point after instantiation?

Comment: It was due to brush1 not getting value assigned in the code, So i assigned a default value and now the code is working fine